# Turn find my iPad off

Tags: ipad, icloud, password

My iPad is showing my old Apple id, so I am unable to sign out of iCloud or turn off "find my iPad" I need to sign out so that I can type in my new Apple id. The system is only allowing my to reset my password or find my apple id

Answer (score 2):

In order to turn off Find My iPad you **have** to have the password to your old AppleID. If you don't you may have to call Apple Support (or go by an Apple Store?) and have them reset the password to that account.

I believe that if you even try and just wipe the iPad it will require that password. No two ways about it you **need** that password.

Yes it is annoying but if anyone could simply turn off find my iphone/ipad that would negate it as a setting to help you find stolen devices.